# Mongodb Query to get only documents in specific days

Tags: mongodb

In my mongodb table, I have 2 (relevant for this Q) columns: `service, timestamp`.
I want to query only rows with `service=liveness` and that those with timestamp of 12th Novermber 2020.

How can I do it, if `timestamp` field is of type `Number` (UNIX epoch number)..?

This is my query currently:
`{ service: "liveness" }`.

This is how the timestamp column looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To query by two fields you only need this syntax:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "field1": yourField1Value,
  "field2": yourField2Value
```

So, if your date is a `Number` instead of a `Date` you can try this query:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "service": "liveness",
  "timestamp": 1600768437934
})
```

And should works. Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pU5kzowlUR2).

Now, if the problem is parse `12th November 2020` to UNIX timestamp, then the easiest way is convert first the date in your app language.

Edit:

Also, I don't know if I've missunderstood your question but, [here is](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bBadT6c8-0D) another query.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "service": "liveness",
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "timestamp": {
        "$toDate": "$timestamp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "timestamp": {
        "$gt": ISODate("1990-01-01"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2060-01-01")
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This query first match all documents with `service` as `liveness`, so the next stage is faster. Into `$project` the timestamp is parsed to `Date` so you can match again with your date.
Using `$gt` and `$lt` you can search by a whole day.

And also, if you can get the days into UNIX timestamp you can do this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "service": "liveness",
  "timestamp": {
    "$gte": yourDay,
    "$lt": nextrDay
  }
})
```

Using `$gte` and `$lt` you ensure the query will find all values in the day.